# Move files back to their original location based on text file

Tags: bash, macos, awk, terminal, find

I have moved a bunch of files with the `mv -v` command. So in the end i have a text file containing something like this:
`

```
 /Volumes/[TV Shows]/Movie 1.avi --> /Volumes/Downloads/Movie 1.avi
 /Volumes/[TV Shows]/Movie 2.mp4 --> /Volumes/Downloads/Movie 2.mp4
```

`

I need to move each file from `Downloads` back to its original location based on this text file. The original location would be the string before the `-->` inside my text file. The matching criteria is the `filename`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

@jeremysprofile

My file can be found here [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5msq5a7tmz3v3bs/myTextFile.txt?dl=0)

On my mac, I have used the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    #use http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal to grab the parts we want
    origin=${line% --> *}
    current=${line#* --> }
    mv -- "$current" "$origin"
done < ~/Desktop/myTextFile.txt
```

The first lines of the result are:

```
WYSIWYG:Desktop cip$ ./myMove.sh
mv: rename /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.s01e01.WEBDL.720p.NewStudio.TV.mkv -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.s01e01.WEBDL.720p.NewStudio.TV.mkv to /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.s01e01.WEBDL.720p.NewStudio.TV.mkv -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.s01e01.WEBDL.720p.NewStudio.TV.mkv: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E02.Polybius.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E02.Polybius.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 to /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E02.Polybius.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E02.Polybius.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E03.Bob.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E03.Bob.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 to /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E03.Bob.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4 -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E03.Bob.HULU.WEBRip.x264-RBB.mp4: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv to /Volumes/Public/English/[Sorted TV Shows]/Dimension/Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv -> /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv: No such file or directory
```

I want to mention that the `/Volume/Public` is correctly mapped on my computer and that the files are existing in the `from_tv_shows` location:

```
WYSIWYG:Desktop cip$ find /Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows/ -name 'Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv'
/Volumes/Public/Downloads/from_tv_shows//Dimension.404.S01E04.WEBRip x264-RMTeam.mkv
WYSIWYG:Desktop cip$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear, please elaborate your problem more in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    #use http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal to grab the parts we want
    origin=${line% --> *}
    current=${line#* --> }
    mv -- "$current" "$origin" 
done < myTextFile.txt
```

We do substring removal, where `%` keeps everything before the substring (so we keep everything before  `-->` ), and `#` keeps everything after (so we keep everything after  `-->` ), with `*` as the multi-character wildcard.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash) is how bash "for line in file" syntax works.

Comment: @hek2mgl That was easily fixed.

Comment: I've created myself a script `myMove.sh`  and tried first to **echo** the `$origin` and `$current`; in order to see if it works, before actually doing the move. And it does not seem to work. Both variables are giving me the whole line.

Comment: @nbnlko, tested and verified; works on my machine with the sample text provided.

Comment: @jeremysprofile I have updated the question with my attempts, and also provided a link to the text file with the original names inside.

Comment: @nbnlko, as you can see from your logs, your text file uses `->` as the delimiter, not `-->` as you originally said. If you change `-->` in my answer to `->`, it will work.

Comment: @jeremysprofile , thank you so much for opening my eyes! Your solution was perfect! Also, thank you for this link http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removalhttp://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal ; it is very useful!

Comment: @nbnlko, if my solution worked, please accept my answer (you will earn a bit of reputation for this action) by clicking on the grey checkmark under the arrows next to my answer.